# Slow Loading product page Image with magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product-images, porto-theme

After an **upgrade** to 2.3.1 images in the product page, are loading very slow and also checkout step got so slow too. We have tried many ways to fix it and we have read that many people has the same problem with the new Magento. We don't understand if is **Magento** or Porto Theme problem, can please somebody help us?

**Thank you very much.**